# How do you implement polymorphism for functions that require different parameters for different derived classes?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have two different derived classes with different type properties.
I need a virtual function in base class to set those properties. Thus, this function requires different types of arguments in different derived classes.

[image: Look at the red text]

I tried to make a interface for property. But the problem is that the `SetProp` of `Drived_1` can receive a parameter of type `Prop_2`.

[image: The red part is changed]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could have multiple `setProp(Type t)` for different types in the base and only really implement them in the derived classes that can deal with that type. It's a bit odd though. Makes me wonder if your class breakdown is correct...

Comment: You can use generics to implement required hierarchy? But will generics help you or not depends on how you intend to use your method `SetProp(p)`?

Comment: I can accept calling this method in other ways, and even write a class for this method. But I don’t want to judge the type of an instance in the code.

Comment: try to refactor this. Inject the functionality you have in base class into derived classes and remove the hierarchy, then see if you can make it generic. if you've done that but still can't figure it out, I suggest asking new question with some example code

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define the method as SetProp where T:xxx (use generics). Would that not work?

Comment: I can't use `where` for constraints on overridden methods. If I use  `where` for constraints in base class methods. This has the same problem as the method mentioned in the question, the problem is I need to judge the type in the overridden methods.  I don’t want to judge the type in the code.